# How to store custom user data on the database?

Tags: multisite, database, user-meta

I'm developing a WP multi-site network which have a goal of 10,000 sub blogs.
The site needs to store custom data related to the user. There are additional 20 fields of data for each user. What is the best way to store data in the WP?

1. Store in a custom table
2. Store in user meta table

I'm using a dedicated server for the database. The specs are
16GB RAM - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X3430 @ 2.40GHz

Store data in the User Meta table will affect to my site's performance?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any data showing that user meta *won't* work? Until you do — don't mess with it. You are not likely to get from-scratch solutions as convenient and more performant without significant effort.

Comment: Native WordPress functions typically use caches to speed up performance, too. Performance enhancements are built right in. e.g., [`get_user_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) uses [`get_metadata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_metadata), which, looking at [the code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.2/src/wp-includes/meta.php), uses a cache.

Comment: I have read some articles related to this. I needed to confirm it before servers going mad. Thanks.